# How can I set an axes scale on $x$ in terms of $\pi$?

Tags: plotting

If I plot a function

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3Pi}]
```

I'll get a plot with the x between 0 and 10.  I'll like to know how I can modify the x axis to have it in terms of Pi. i.e. to have 0, Pi/2, Pi on the x axis instead of 1,2,3....

Comment: If you look in the help page for `Ticks` you should find an example that shows almost exactly what you are describing. You might be able to guess how to modify that example like this `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2, 2 Pi, 5 Pi/2, 3 Pi}, {-1, 1}}]` and you should be done

Comment: @Bill This could be further simplified (by some definition of simplification) to solutions like `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {FindDivisions[{0, 10, Pi/2}, 10], Automatic}]`

Comment: @kirma When dealing with what appear to be very new users I have found the definition of simplification being "introduce no more than trivial typo fixes and no more than one new concept in any response" seems to work best for me. I hope that it works best for them too.

Comment: duplicates: [Axes labels as multiples of Pi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94606/125) and [Multi graphs in one plot with axis labels in multiples of Pi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180209/125)

Comment: @kirma in terms of computing time is there any difference between use the list or use the FindDivisions comand?

Comment: @HeberleyTobónMaya Shouldn't make a difference in practice. Computing ticks consumes insignificant amount of time; it's more a question of how much time *you* use to write the code for it. I must admit remembering `FindDivisions` took couple seconds for me, so @Bill's method may be faster in practice... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to do what you ask is to add a [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) option that places $x$-axis ticks at intervals of `Pi/2`.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, Ticks -> {Subdivide[0, 3 Pi, 3 Pi/(Pi/2)], Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The number of intervals in Ticks can be specified as an integer:       

    Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, Ticks -> {Subdivide[0, 3 Pi, 6], Automatic}]