# How to control the labeling of axes in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

I'd like to change the labeling on the axes of a contour plot so that they are multiples of $\pi$. Any thoughts?

e.g. [image: See below]

ContourPlot[ Sin[x]* Cos[4 y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate: [Multi graphs in one plot with axis labels in multiples of Pi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180209/125) and [Axes labels as multiples of π](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94606/125)

Comment: `ContourPlot[Sin[x]*Cos[4 y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/4], 
    None}, {Range[0, \[Pi], \[Pi]/4], None}}]`

Comment: @kglr Thanks for reference. Strange how this page didn't show up in search...

Comment: @Okkes Dulgerci Thanks!